# Clojure post-condition fails to execute due to syntax error -- why?

Tags: compilation, clojure, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, post-conditions

In this function:

```
(defn my-post 
  [a] 
  {:post (number? %)}
  a)
```

The post-condition doesn't execute (or at least, doesn't cause an assertion error).  I now know that it should have been:

```
(defn my-post 
  [a] 
  {:post [(number? %)]} ;; note the square brackets around the expression
  a)
```

Which does, in fact, work correctly.

The problem is that this failed silently, and took me a while to figure out what was wrong.  No syntax errors, runtime exceptions.

**I would like to understand what Clojure does with this code, in order to understand why Clojure didn't complain.**  Macro expansions?  Destructuring?  Does the code just disappear if it doesn't see square braces?

Comment: Please explain what is this post condition? I'm unable to figure out what is this method purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://clojure.org/special_forms documents that the condition-map for `fn` (thus also `defn`) should be of the form:

```
{:pre [pre-expr*]
 :post [post-expr*]}
```

`{:post (number? %)}` will result in `(number? %)` being treated as a sequence of assertions, which means it's interpreted as two separate assertions: `number?` and `%`.

```
user> (macroexpand-1 '(fn [a] {:post (number? %)} a))
(fn*
 ([a]
  (clojure.core/let [% a]
   (clojure.core/assert number?)
   (clojure.core/assert %)
   %)))
```

`(assert number?)` always passes as long as `number?` is defined and has a true value, which being a core function, it probably does.  `(clojure.core/assert %)` passes if `%` has a true value.  It's bound to the value of your argument `a` via the `let`, so it passes if `a` has a true value.  Try calling `(my-post nil)` with your first function definition and it'll fail the assertion.

```
user> (my-post nil)
; Evaluation aborted.
; Assert failed: %
;  [Thrown class java.lang.AssertionError]
```

If you properly put your post-condition in a vector, it expands like this:

```
user> (macroexpand-1 '(fn [a] {:post [(number? %)]} a))
(fn*
 ([a]
  (clojure.core/let [% a]
   (clojure.core/assert (number? %))
   %)))
```